# Terraform state replace-provider update state with wrong data

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

We upgraded terraform version and we have a problem with terraform remote state. Basiacaly I run  this command to update azurerm provider:

```
terraform state replace-provider 'registry.terraform.io/-/azurerm' 'registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm'
```

Right now when I run plan command it shows me some errors. All are the same but resource if different. For example:

```
To work with module.name.module.lb_name.azurerm_lb_probe.instance
its original provider configuration at
provider["registry.terraform.io/-/azurerm"] is required, but it has been
removed. This occurs when a provider configuration is removed while objects
created by that provider still exist in the state. Re-add the provider
configuration to destroy
module.name.module.lb_name.azurerm_lb_probe.instance, after which
you can remove the provider configuration again.
```

Basically the state was updated and the provider looks like this:

```
"provider": "provider.azurerm"
```

but it should look like this:

```
"provider": "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm\"]"
```

Is there any way to update it via terraform commands or the only way to fix it is to edit state file manually?

Comment: " shows me some errors" - is not specific. What are the errors exactly?

Comment: I updated the question with an example. We had similar issue od other environment and the resolution was to update provider in state files as I mentioned before. The problem is that it occured on Production environment and we just don't want to modify it manually.

Comment: Isn't there a CLI tool provided by Terraform to help with changes between versions, something like `0.12upgrade` and `0.13upgrade`?

Comment: According to the error message, the provider needs to be updated for the relevant module also. This could also mean updating the required providers block in the module itself, and then replacing the provider in the state again for the module.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

When you replace the providers for the Terraform upgrade with the command:

```
terraform state replace-provider 'registry.terraform.io/-/azurerm' 'registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm'
```

OK, there is no problem. And then you can use the command below to check the current providers:

```
terraform providers
```

The screenshot will show like this:

[image]

At this time, the providers are the same as the requirement. Then you need to init again to pull the current providers to replace the existing ones with the command below:

```
terraform init
```

[image]

This is the step you have missed.